Authenticate in MTProto without needing to get api_id & api_hash
I wondered how Telegram desktop, Android or any official Telegram app does authentication?
I mean, we can use MTProto with pyrogram or telethon, but we need api_hash and api_id. But in Telegram desktop, we are only asked for our phone_number and by entering the code, we can use MTProto.
I noticed that this is also present in those clients. But does this mean that we can also build our own clients using api_id and api_hash mentioned there, and this won't be a problem?

All clients need api id & hash, Telegram desktop uses the official api id & hash in its source code and does not ask you for it anymore, you can use the following published api id & hash 
https://telegra.ph/telegraph-01-31-6

While it's true using the API needs API ID and hash, one should not use the API ID and hash pairs of others. They are secret. Using them will more likely lead to accounts being banned. A developer should register their application and use their own pair for what they develop.
